# React + Gsap loop scroll

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scroll, gsap, infinite

I just want to know wether someone knows how to create an loop vertical scroll using react and gsap.
Thank you in advance!!
i tried to use some links but didn't work for my project: https://codepen.io/willtchou/pen/abqmgMa

````
<div className="appli-cards-list" ref={listRef}>
                    <ApplicationCard
                        applicationCardImageProps={{
                            color1: "#57DDFF",
                            color2: "#7315A2",
                            name: "TodoApp",
                        }}
                        date={2021}
                    />
                    <ApplicationCard
                        applicationCardImageProps={{
                            color1: "#DCDCDC",
                            color2: "#A4181b",
                            name: "Kurama",
                        }}
                        date={2021}
                    />
                    <ApplicationCard
                        applicationCardImageProps={{
                            color1: "#E0C341",
                            color2: "#0274be",
                            name: "Chalets and Caviar",
                        }}
                        date={2022}
                    />
                    <ApplicationCard
                        applicationCardImageProps={{
                            color1: "#1DA1F2",
                            color2: "#0F611E",
                            name: "Watch It Outside",
                        }}
                        date={2022}
</div>```
````